# Do XMLHttpRequests cache the response headers?

Tags: ajax, http, caching, http-headers

If I make an XMLHttpRequest and the browser caches the response, will it also cache the HTTP response headers? That is, the next time I make the same request, will I get the same values back from `response.getResponseHeader`?

Is this browser-dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers are either not cached or not reused. Since a request is sent, headers are received and only then can be decided if this request is valid in the cache. The new headers have then already been downloaded, so no point in reusing the old ones.

Only the response body is cached.

You could ofcourse very easily test this. Make a XHR request to a static resource (img or txt file or something) and check the `Date` header.

I don't think it's browser dependant. A browser caching and reusing HTTP headers would be very, very strange.

**edit**
jQuery adds (by default I think) anti caching arguments to GET requests (very annoying), which would sort-of answer your question: nothing is cached like that.

Comment: But do all XHRs make an actual request to the server? When you link to a cached image or stylesheet, sometimes the browser just reuses it without even talking to the server. Does this never happen with XHRs?

Comment: If you specifically make a request, the browser makes that request. With images and stylesheets, you don't specifically make that request. If you want to be absolutely 100% sure, you can add a no cache argument like jQuery does: `page.html?_=324832475934`

Answer (score 1):

I'm certain at least the major browsers don't try to cache the headers. However, if you want to prevent caching altogether, you may need to send special headers. If you want to do a quick test of caching behaviors, there's a page here:

http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/cache.html

And I recommend if you want to see what's actually happening, that you go get a packet sniffer such as Wireshark and see for yourself. I can imagine the browser at least performs a HEAD request for an XmlHttpRequest even if it gives you the cached body, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You are not wrong. Headers are required to even know the cache is still valid.